# Submited Ajax form contain no data in action : ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Partial View in my Home view that Post a View Model into Partial.
I tried to use Ajax.beginform to submit my data with ajax but when I submit form the Model in my Action contain no data. I do this steps:

1) Create my view and Create a partial and call the partial in my view liek this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("/partials/objects/_Partial_Poll.cshtml", Poll);}
```

Poll is my ObjectModel that I fill it's properties.

2) I define my Partial like this:

```
@model ObjectModel.Poll
@{
Layout = null;
int counter = 0;
}
<script src="/Content/Templates/Main/fa-ir/Files/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>

<aside class="p-box p-tablerow">
<div class="p-head"><span class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></span>&nbsp; poll     </div>
<table cellspacing="0" id="pollfrm">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">@Model.Title</td>
        </tr>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SavePoll","Poll",new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "pollfrm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        foreach (var item in Model.PollReplies)
        {
            counter++;
            <tr>
                <td>@counter</td>
                <td>@item.Title</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButton("PollRep", item.ID, item.IsChecked)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
</aside>

<script>
$(function () {

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            alert(this.action);
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#pollfrm').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

3) I define my Action like this:

```
[Route("_SavePoll")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _SavePoll(ObjectModel.Poll _poll) 
{
   return Content("Thanks", "text/html");
}
```

4)

```
public Poll() {
    {
        PollReplies = new List<PollReply>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<PollReply> PollReplies { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Poll Object model.

```
public class PollReply
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Poll_ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my PollReply Object model that related to Poll Object model.

when I run my project and select one radiobutton and submit the form evrything work well, but _poll in

```
public ActionResult _SavePoll(ObjectModel.Poll _poll)
```

contain no data!

Comment: You need to show the model for `Poll` (your generating form controls with name attributes that have no relationship to your model properties)

Comment: And why on earth are you using `Ajax.BeginForm()` then writing a script that cancels it but does exactly what `Ajax.BeginForm()` would have done anyway?

Comment: I Edit my question and show the model for `Poll`

Comment: Your view code makes no sense. What are you trying to bind to. (currently you creating radio buttons for a property named `PollRep` which does not exist)

Comment: I have no problem in get method. My problem is just when I submit form, the `ObjectModel.Poll _poll` contain no data  in `_SavePoll` Action!

Comment: Of course it doesn't (read my comments). What are you trying to bind to? (your code makes no sense)

Comment: I have one main view that my partial rendered into that. in my main view I call a function that bind my model and I pass it's into partial .

Comment: Which part about _"What are you trying to bind to?"_ do you not understand!

Comment: `ObjectModel.Poll Poll = PollServices._GetPollWithLang(3, language);` I used this code to get my Poll and post the poll from my main view to partial like this `@{Html.RenderPartial("/partials/objects/_Partial_Poll.cshtml", Poll);}`

Comment: I did not understand your question! What you need to know?

Comment: Read my 3rd comment carefully. You are attempting to bind to a property of your `Poll` model named `PollRep` but your model DOES NOT contain a property named `PollRep`. AGAIN What property are you trying to bind to?

Comment: I am attempting to bind to a property of my `Poll` model named `PollReplies` not `PollRep` . `PollRep` is just my Radiobuttons name for always select one!

Comment: `PollReplies` is a list in my `Poll` model.

Comment: You ARE attempting to bind to a property named `PollRep` because that is what you have named the control! And `PollReplies` is collection of complex objects. A radio button group only posts back a single value (for example it can bind to a property of type `int` or string`) NOT a complex object and certainly not a collection of complex objects. I suggest you spend some time learning the basics